# Array is filled with undefined values (Erlang)

Tags: arrays, erlang

**Updated Question; Original below.**

I am trying to create an array which represents a grid of cells, which have tuples containing the walls they are surrounded by.
I have come up with this:

```
rooms(Array) ->
  Size = array:size(Array),
  if       
    Size == ?HSIZE * ?VSIZE ->
      Array;
    true ->
      HFactor = Size rem ?VSIZE,
      VFactor = Size div ?HSIZE,
      Room = {1+HFactor+11*VFactor,
              7+HFactor+11*VFactor,
              12+HFactor+11*VFactor,
              6+HFactor+11*VFactor},
      rooms(array:set(Size, Room, Array))
  end.
```

When I run this with `rooms(array:new()).` I get the following array back:

```
{array,25,100,undefined,
   {{{1,7,12,6},
     {2,8,13,7},
     {3,9,14,8},
     {4,10,15,9},
     {5,11,16,10},
     {12,18,23,17},
     {13,19,24,18},
     {14,20,25,19},
     {15,21,26,20},
     {16,22,27,21}},
    {{23,29,34,28},
     {24,30,35,29},
     {25,31,36,30},
     {26,32,37,31},
     {27,33,38,32},
     {34,40,45,39},
     {35,41,46,40},
     {36,42,47,41},
     {37,43,48,42},
     {38,44,49,43}},
    {{45,51,56,50},
     {46,52,57,51},
     {47,53,58,52},
     {48,54,59,53},
     {49,55,60,54},
     undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined},
    10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10}}
```

Which is quite close to the desired result, but there are two things I can't quite put my finger on (The numbers are correct). Why does it look like it is split up into multiple subarrays? What are those undefineds and 10's doing there? These are mostly due to my lack of erlang knowledge, because array:get produces the expected results, but I couldn't find anything which explains where they come from.

---

**Original Question**

```
rooms(Array) ->
  Size = array:size(Array),
  if 
    Size == 5 ->
      Array;
    Size rem 5 == 0 ->
      rooms(array:set(Size, array:new(), Array));
    true -> 
      In_Array = array:get(array:size(Array), Array),
      In_Size = array:size(In_Array),
      Room = {1+In_Size+11*In_Size,
              7+In_Size+11*In_Size,
              12+In_Size+11*In_Size,
              6+In_Size+11*In_Size},
      New_In = array:set(In_Size, Room, In_Array),
      rooms(array:set(Size, New_In, Array))
  end.
```

I call it with `rooms(array:new()).` but the result is

```
** exception error: bad argument
 in function  array:size/1 (array.erl, line 317)
 in call from framework_kamer:rooms/1 (framework_kamer.erl, line 195)
```

Which makes sense because In_Array is not an array, but undefined. However, I can't figure out why. 
Side question, is there an easier/cleaner/better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You are (in the second call of the recursion) trying

```
In_Array = array:get(array:size(Array), Array),
```

As `array` is zero-indexed this will always fail, as the access will be always be off by one. Change this line to

```
In_Array = array:get(array:size(Array) - 1, Array),
```

and you are fine.

A few comments on your code:

- Conventional variable naming in Erlang would be CamelCase without underscores (i.e. `InArray`)
- Expressing a 2-dimensional array as nested arrays is almost never a good idea. Linearalise it by writing simple wrappers that recalculate a one-dimensional index from `x` and `y` as `index = y * max_x + x`.

Comment: It isn't supposed to be empty, since the Size rem 5 == 0 clause sets a new array every time it reaches a new 'line' in the array. At least that is my intention.
Thanks for the two extra tips, probably going to refactor it like that but I don't think it will fix the current problem, right?

Comment: See the latest change, sorry for the wrong first answer :)

Comment: That did get it closer to the desired result, but I found some other problems, which were actually fixed by using a flat array. I updated my question with what I have now plus a new question that arose..

Comment: Please create a new question for this.

Comment: Or actually, I can answer it in this comment directly, what you see there is the internal representation of an `array`. You can infer by poking a bit around that the arrays are stored in buckets of 10.